# Pagination of the query result in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

--
I have implemented a search functionality in my app. It returns a joined tables, so basically the data of the query results comes from different tables.

This is an example of results:

```
    $selectSQL =    'SELECT
                    agencies.agency, agencies.website_url, agencies.status, agencies.size, agencies.profession, agencies.sector, agencies.id, OfficeData.id, ContactData.name, ContactData.surname, ContactData.job_title, ContactData.email, 
                    ContactData.direct_line, OfficeCountryData.country, OfficeData.switchboard, agencies.industry
                    FROM agencies';
    $sql2='         LEFT JOIN  offices  AS OfficeData ON (agencies.id = OfficeData.agency_id AND OfficeData.hq = "1")
                    LEFT JOIN countries AS OfficeCountryData ON OfficeData.hq = OfficeCountryData.id
                    LEFT JOIN contacts AS ContactData ON agencies.id = ContactData.agency_id
                    ';
    $whereSQL = ' WHERE 1 = 1 AND ProfessionData.profession_id = 3'
    $groupBySQL = 'GROUP BY agencies.id ORDER BY agencies.id ASC';
    $resultAgencies = $this->Agency->query($selectSQL . $sql2 . $whereSQL . $groupBySQL);
```

Now I would like to fetch the results so they are compatible with paginator.
I've tried doing it but there were always many errors.

Comment: what paginator? And what errors did you get?

Comment: The main problem is that when I click a column name to sort results - everything dissapears.

Comment: if you don't use paginator component, don't use paginator helper. You'll need to make the columns sorted on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The strenght of CakePHP is that it does all the work for you. Do you have proper [relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) setup? That way you shouldn't need to write your own queries. I've been working with Cake for the last two years, doing complicated stuff and never had to write my own queries.

Your queries don't seem to be really complicated, so I doubt they can't be done in CakePHP. It has many benefits, such as pagination and increased security...

In case you can't, maybe a hint...

CakePHP gives you results in associative arrays, so you should convert your result to that format:

```
array('Model' => array('field1', 'field2'))
```

This way you can construct it yourself.